# How to find all children from another table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables

**CATEGORY**

```
id   category     parent_id
1    Electronic
2    Furniture
3    Phone        1
4    LCD          1
5    Watch        1
6    Desk         2
```

**ORDER**

```
id customer product      category_id
1  John     Smartphone   3
2  Marry    Montior      4
3  King     Wood-Desk    6
```

I want to find all of **electronic** result by child_id.

Like this..

```
SELECT product FROM order WHERE category_id = (category.id = 1)
```

**RESULT**

```
product
Smartphone
Monitor
```

Is there any expression like this in MySQL?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You can look into [JOIN's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) (which is a common way to fetch related data from more than one table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `join` for this. You also will need to encapsulate the `order` table name with backticks because `order` is reserved (alternatively you could rename that table to save yourself from encapsulating everytime).

```
SELECT product FROM `order` as o 
join category as c 
on o.category_id = c.id 
WHERE c.parent_id = 1
```

The `on` tells the DB what to data to `join` on. The `as` creates an alias so the full table name doesn't need to be written out everytime. (The `as` also is optional, I find it easier to read, `` FROM `order` o `` would be the same)

An alternative approach could be using a sub-query:

```
SELECT product 
FROM `order` 
WHERE category_id in (SELECT id FROM CATEGORY where parent_id = 1)
```

Comment: on o.category_id = c.id makes more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use INNER JOIN

```
SELECT order.product 
FROM order
INNER JOIN category
ON order.category_id = category.id
WHERE category.parent_id = 1
```

The ON keyword shows what columns will be compare between these tables. When you make a JOIN you need to put the table name before the column name separated with "." because it is possible to exist a column with the same name in both tables.

Comment: Have another look at the tables. It should be all the categories with`parent_id = 1`. The `category`  table doesn't have any column called `category_id`.